# I'm trying to delete an image from a DB using AJAX, code works but cant tranverse DOM and hide image, why?

Tags: jquery, click, this

```
$('.deleteImage a').click(function() {

alert('Delete this?');
 $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: this,
    success: function(){
    $(this).hide('slow');
    }
    });


return false;
});
```

Comment: Please make more effort when asking. Like formatting. Or explaining the error. Or giving a testable code. Or spelling.

Comment: You have to keep reference on this using a var or a closure or jquery $.proxy

Comment: The title needs to be improved, the question needs to be... in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.deleteImage a').click(function() {

var thiz = $(this); // references the '.deleteImage a'

alert('Delete this?');
 $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: this,
    success: function(){
        thiz.hide('slow'); //$(this) references to the ajax, use our thiz to reference to '.deleteImage a'
    }
    });


return false;
});
```

read the comments

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain correctly my question. I'm not an english native speaker but this answer is what I was trying to do. Thanks !!

Comment: @user2141697 No problem. Don't forget to click on the green tick (V) to mark as answered. And I suggest you try later edit the question so other people with same problem could understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using a closure:

```
$('.deleteImage a').click(function () {

    alert('Delete this?');
    (function (self) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: self,//strange url!!!
            success: function () {
                $(self).hide('slow');
            }
        });
    })(this);

    return false;
});
```